# Why can the continuous function of a non compact set be compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, closed-map

for example: $S_1=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2\leq 1,\ x,y,\geq 0\} \\ S_2=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2 < 1,\ x,y,\geq 0\}$

Why is $f(S_2) = S_1$ possible but $f(S_1) = S_2$ isn't?

I'm using the definition of compactness from Bolzano-Weierstrass
theorem

What is the criteria for the existence of such function?
What is the general way of finding such continuous function if it exist?

Comment: Please define $f$ .

Comment: What's your preferred definition of compactness? You've tagged [tag:general-topology], so I'm guessing you prefer finite open subcovers to sequential compactness?

Comment: The answer to your question is: because limit points of a set may be mapped to the interior of a compact set.

Comment: I've changed the last sentence to what I believe you meant. Please roll back and clarify if I misunderstood.

Comment: On your edit: Criteria with what given? For example every set can be mapped to a compact set simply by a constant function: The image is a singleton (containing only that constant) and therefore compact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of a continuous function $f$ such that $f(S_2)=S_1$ is $f(x,y) =\sin^{2}(2\pi (x^{2}+y^{2})) (u,v)$ for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$, $f(0,0)=0$ where $u=\frac x {\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}}}$ and $v=\frac y {\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}}}$. There is no continuous function $f$ such that $f(S_1)=S_2$ because continuous image of  a compact set is compact.

Comment: How is such continuous function founded?

Comment: @smaillis All you need is a continuous function from $[0,1)$ onto $[0,1]$. So I looked for a  continuous function which has the same value at $0$ and $1$ thereby making the image of $[0,1)$ same as the image of $[0,1]$.